# Node.js: How to create an array from a string and another array?

Tags: node.js

Can someone explain to me if it is possible to create a new array from an array and a string?
Example:

I have this array:

```
let array = ['value1', 'value2']
```

And this string:

```
let testString = 'value3';
```

and I want to create an array from these two, which should look like this:

```
['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
```

How do I get this result? Is there a direct method for this or do I have to solve this with a loop?

Comment: `array.concat(testSring)` will create a new array with the value added `array.push(testString)` will add it to the current array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use concat which will return a new array or you can use ES6 spread operator to create a new array with the new element.

```
const array = ['value1', 'value2'];
const testString= 'value3';

//Concat method
const newArrayMethod1 = array.concat(testString);

// ES6 spread operator method
const newArrayMethod2 = [...array, testString];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array = ['value1', 'value2']
let testString = 'value3';

array.push(testString)
console.log(array)
```